# Getting value of combobox in other form c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I try to get the value of a `ComboBox` in another form, but I won't get any.

When I use a `MessageBox` on `Form1` with the selected value I get indeed the value I used to be.

When I try it on `Form2` I get a blank `MessageBox`, so in this way I won't be able to use the "IF" statement to get the data I want.

Form1:

```
namespace ScoreDuizenden
{
    public partial class AantalSpelers : Form
    {
        public AantalSpelers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string si;
        public void AantalSpelers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NaamSpelers ns = new NaamSpelers();
            cbAantalSpelers.Items.Add("2");
            cbAantalSpelers.Items.Add("3");
            cbAantalSpelers.Items.Add("4");

        }
        public void btnDoorgaan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            si = cbAantalSpelers.Text;
            NaamSpelers ns = new NaamSpelers();
            ns.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
namespace ScoreDuizenden
{
    public partial class NaamSpelers : Form
    {
        public NaamSpelers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        AantalSpelers asp = new AantalSpelers();

        private void NaamSpelers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (asp.cbAantalSpelers.Text == "2")
            {
                label3.Hide();
                label4.Hide();
                txtNaam3.Hide();
                txtNaam4.Hide();
                btnAsDoorgaan.Location = new Point(16, 62);
                this.Size = new Size(198, 130);
            }
            if (asp.cbAantalSpelers.Text == "3")
            {
                label4.Hide();
                txtNaam4.Hide();
                btnAsDoorgaan.Location = new Point(16, 88);
                this.Size = new Size(198, 157);
            }
        }

        private void NaamSpelers_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void btnAsDoorgaan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(asp.si);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: because the combo box is emtpy. `AantalSpelers_Load` is never called because you don't call show. all of this code is pretty bad. You could pass the first form as parameter and use that instead of creating a new one without any values

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `public NaamSpelers(AantalSpelers form)` and `NaamSpelers ns = new NaamSpelers(this);`

Comment: It diddn't work :(

Comment: I think you should really first learn the basics of c# before you play with winforms. you need to know what methods are, contructors, parameters, references etc...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see below code

Form 1:

```
namespace ScoreDuizenden
{
    public partial class AantalSpelers : Form
    {
        public AantalSpelers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string si;
        public void AantalSpelers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NaamSpelers ns = new NaamSpelers();
            cbAantalSpelers.Items.Add("2");
            cbAantalSpelers.Items.Add("3");
            cbAantalSpelers.Items.Add("4");

        }
        public void btnDoorgaan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            si = cbAantalSpelers.Text;
            NaamSpelers ns = new NaamSpelers(si); // passing value to form through constructor
            ns.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
    namespace ScoreDuizenden
    {
        public partial class NaamSpelers : Form
        {
            private string cbAntalSpelers = string.Empty; // class level field to store combo value
            public NaamSpelers(string cboValue)  // combo value need to be passed to this form whenever a new instance is created
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.cbAntalSpelers = cboValue;
            }

            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: @EmielvanLeeuwen, thanks mate, please have a look at the link in your free time https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors